# Is there a name for this kind of Bug?

Tags: naming

Is there a special name for a Bug that is caused by a change in code that can't possibly cause a change in behaviour?

Like the bug caused by changing this

```
...
X x = (X)getX();
...
Object getX(){
    ...
    return someReturnValue;
}
```

to

```
...
X x = getX();
...
X getX(){
    ...
    return (X)someReturnValue;
}
```

Comment: Why is it a bug if it can't cause a change in behaviour? Also, seems a bit off topic for SO, not sure where it would fit.

Comment: @Dukeling Well, it actually does change the bevaviour in very 'interesting' ways. In case of the the example the class containing that code is a Spring Bean. Therefore Springs search for annotations causes the class X to be loaded during creation of the Spring Context which in turn triggers the actual Bug, which doesn't happen when X is only loaded later.